# Solr Metrics Number confusion

Tags: solr

We are wanting to start using the Solr metrics, example web API call below:

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/metrics?type=counter&group=core.bookings

We get results back like this from our master

[image]

We get metrics like this from our slave that does all the serving

[image]

The question is what are the **totalTime** values measure in? If we presume they are milliseconds, that would mean that each request was taking 0.8 of a day, and that is just not right! Can someone help describe what units of measure the totalTime is in?

Comment: Please include relevant details as text - images are bad for accessibility, can't be search for properly, and any details can't generally be copy/pasted by those who are reading the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tracing the source, this is [based on the value returned from the metrics timing object](https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/main/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/RequestHandlerBase.java#L23), which [is given in nanoseconds](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-core/3.1.2/com/codahale/metrics/Timer.Context.html#stop--):

```
long elapsed = timer.stop();
metrics.totalTime.inc(elapsed);
```

.. so it's nanoseconds, not milliseconds. This seems to make sense if we take the numbers and divided them:

```py
>>> total = 718781574846646
>>> requests = 6789073
>>> total / requests
105873301.82583779
>>> time_per_request = total / requests
>>> time_per_request / 1_000_000_000
0.10587330182583779
```

.. so about 0.1s per request on average.

Comment: Perfect thank you @MatsLindh, could't see this anywhere in the Solr metrics documentation.